# Unknown Column in field list when already in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen the solutions on stackoverflow so far for this problem and each seem to be different.. So i've decided to open a new question.

My objective is to create a rank column using ascending damage...

```
SET @rownum := 0;

SELECT rank, damage, playerID FROM (
                        SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, damage, playerID
                        FROM PlayerStats WHERE playerID > 20130000000000 ORDER BY damage DESC, modified ASC
                    ) as result WHERE playerID='20130000000004'
```

However, it reports back with 'unknown column "damage" in field list'

```
"playerID","ancientBossID","damage","eventEnergy"

"20130000000004","2012000000000382","19033","38"
"20130000000078","2012000000000019","0","30"
"20130000000066","2012000000000242","0",30"
"20130000000080","2012000000000024","270","25"
"20130000000041","2012000000000133","5808","2"
"20130000000071","2012000000000030","694","30"
"20130000000055","2012000000000189","0","30"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query with cosmetic changes, main of which is initialization of `@rownum` in the subquery

```
SELECT rank, damage, playerID 
FROM 
(
  SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rank, damage, playerID
    FROM PlayerStats, (SELECT @rownum := 0) n
   WHERE playerID > 20130000000000 
   ORDER BY damage DESC, modified
) r 
-- WHERE playerID='20130000000004'
ORDER BY rank
```

And it works perfectly fine.
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caa81/4)** demo.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. Im still scratching my head on why my original query couldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rank, damage, playerID,modified FROM (
                        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY damage DESC, modified ASC)  AS rank, damage, playerID,modified
                        FROM PlayerStats WHERE playerID > 20130000000000 
                    ) as result WHERE playerID='20130000000004'
```